# Why does ORDER BY in OVER clause also affect on my result set?

Tags: sql, oracle

When i write:

```
SELECT deptno,ename, RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY sal DESC) rank 
FROM emp
```

I get result set ordered by sal and deptno, but why? I did not specified it in main `ORDER BY` ?

Comment: Oracle will simply not waste CPU and memory to *undo* the sort.

Comment: It has probably already done the sort for the rank, so why randomize the elements again? On the other hand, I know of no guarantee that it _is_ sorted either.

Comment: When you don't specify order explicitly database engine can return results in any order it want to. You should not be surprised when it changes because of other parts of the query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't specify a main `ORDER BY`, the order in which you receive your results is unspecified, and will be whatever the database system finds easiest. It is often assumed that the default order is the physical order in which the rows are stored on disk, but that is incorrect, that is simply what is often (not always) easiest for the database.

In this specific case, ordering all of the results makes it easier to calculate the rank, and still gives you the results you ask for.